# Don't work git in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

Before reinstalling Android Studio git worked well. But after reinstalling it asks to write the "Path to Git executable". May be some know where is situated git.exe file in the Android Studio folder? I wouldn't like to install any separate version control systems. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install git on your computer first. in my case on Ubuntu I installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

in terminal and followed by :

```
git config --global user.name "NewUser"

git config --global user.email newuser@example.com
```

for configurations.
That's it and now it works perfectly.